# Deleting rows with values higher than the minimum value of all rows with the same id using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

So, i have the following dataframe:

```
        id    value
  0     a       1
  1     a       1
  2     a       2
  3     b       3
  4     b       3
```

For example, for rows with id 'a', the minimum value is 1 and for id 'b', the minimum value is 3, so no rows would be deleted.

Output:

```
        id    value
  0     a       1
  1     a       1
  2     b       3
  3     b       3
```

So far, I've only grouped the rows with same id and found their lowest values but couldn't find a way to delete all expected rows.
I've used the following command:

```
min_values = df.loc[df.groupby(['id'])['value'].idxmin()]['value']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `transform`( `idxmin`: will only return the first index of min value , in your case you have duplicates so it would not return all index )

```
df[df.value==df.groupby('id').value.transform('min')]
Out[257]: 
  id  value
0  a      1
1  a      1
3  b      3
4  b      3
```